# Longest path in a binary tree with at most one turn

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have faced this question in an interview.

Given a binary tree, find the longest path length with at most one turn.
one end of the path has to be a leaf. Other end can be a leaf or any node.

Turn is defined as:

```
In tree1-> start from 1 and there is a turn at root 2 towards right,
In tree2-> starts from 3 goes in left and there is a turn at 1 towards right ,
In tree3-> starts from 1 goes in right and there is a turn at 3 towards left,

     2                 3                 1
    / \               /                   \
   1   3             1                     3
                      \                    /
                       2                  2
```

Can some one help on how to proceed.Thanks..

EDIT:
I was asked this question as a follow up question to Diameter of the tree question during the interview.

My implementation of diameter of the tree goes like this.

variable `'res'` contains the final answer.

```
int maxPathSumUtil(struct Node *root, int &res)
{
    // Base case
    if (root==NULL) return 0;

    // Find maximum sum in left and right subtree. Also find
    // maximum root to leaf sums in left and right subtrees
    // and store them in lLPSum and rLPSum
    int lLPSum = maxPathSumUtil(root->left, res);
    int rLPSum = maxPathSumUtil(root->right, res);

    // Find the maximum path sum passing through root
    int curr_sum = max(lLPSum+rLPSum+root->data);

    // Update res (or result) if needed
    if (res < curr_sum)
        res = curr_sum;

    // Return the maximum root to leaf path sum
    return max(lLPSum, rLPSum)+root->data;
}
```

Initially I thought I can come up with solution using a variable like 'turns' and keeping track the turns variable at every node.

But I am little lost tracking the  turns in the binary tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use dynamic programming.

Let:

```
d[i] = longest path with at most one turn node such that i is the turn node
d_up[i, dir] = longest straight path from i to one of its ancestors
               coming from direction dir
d_down[i, dir] = similarly, except going to descendants.
```

We have:

```
d[i] = max(d_up[i, R] + d_down[i, R],
           d_up[i, R] + d_down[i, L],
           d_up[i, L] + d_down[i, R],
           d_up[i, L] + d_down[i, L],
           d_down[i, L] + d_down[i, R])
```

These can all be computed with a single DFS traversal from any node. Pseudocode:

```
DFS(i, direction):

  if i.left != null:
    d_up[i.left, L] = d_up[i, L] + 1
    d_down[i, L] = 1 + DFS(i.left, L)

  if i.right != null:
    d_up[i.right, R] = d_up[i, R] + 1
    d_down[i, R] = 1 + DFS(i.right, R)

  d[i] = max(d_up[i, R] + d_down[i, R],
             d_up[i, R] + d_down[i, L],
             d_up[i, L] + d_down[i, R],
             d_up[i, L] + d_down[i, L],
             d_down[i, L] + d_down[i, R])

  return 0
```

There might be some off by 1 errors, please point them out if so, but it should work. Complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Technically, Isn't this memoization though?